# Django PostGIS Locally Installing / Running

Tags: django, macos, installation, osx-mountain-lion, postgis

I'm trying to follow the [steps listed here](http://pageworthy.com/blog/postgis-on-mountain-lion/) to get PostGIS working with Postgresql and Django on 0SX 10.8 Mountain Lion. However, when I get to step 6: `createdb -U USERNAME -E utf8 geodjango` I get an error:

```
createdb: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

How can I move forward with the installation process here? Is this the right method? Thanks for your ideas!